# SSL Certificate Issue for HTTPS GET request and not for HTTPS POST request

Tags: java, ssl-certificate

I am trying to write a java program to fetch call records from Empirix server. In order to fetch call records, first I need to generate a token id by sending a HTTPS POST request to a server https://webserver:8443/openam/json/authenticate. The inputs for the POST request will be my username and password. Once I fetch the token id, I am sending that as input to HTTPS GET request to same webserver but different port (https://webserver:443/restapi/v1/emergencyCalls/) fetch call records.

I have got the server certificate and stored it in keystore (cacerts). I am successfully able to get 200 ok response for POST method but I get - 
"Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target" issue when I call GET method in my program.

I have tested the connection using SSLPoke class and I am getting Successful Connection for java -Djavax.net.debug=all SSLPoke  webserver 8443 
I get the issue when I run java -Djavax.net.debug=all SSLPoke webserver 443

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure how your app is configured but I recognize that error. The certificate is not where your application expects it to be. If you're able to print out the path it's using to retrieve the cert before it does, that may help.

Comment: Hi Josh. I have added the server certs into keystore (cacerts) in all the three locations where java is present - Program Files, Program Files 86 and local user folder. The strange thing is HTTPS POST method returns me result without any cert issue. It is happening only for HTTPS GET.

Comment: Hi Josh. I got the issue resolved. While importing the certificate I had just imported server cert. I had to import the Root CA as well. Thank you for your advice in resolving the issue.

Comment: @user2267886 no worries